# Deploying Node/mongodb app to GKE and it keeps failing with crashloopbackoff

Tags: node.js, mongodb, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I deployed my nodejs/typeScript container alongside mongodb image on GKE. But the nodejs app deployment keeps failing, and I know because I can't hit the server with the external IP address and port. When I inspect the deployment on GCP console, I see that it fails with error: `Does not have minimum availability` and `crashloopbackoff`.
From the logs I could also see that the app fails to connect to the database I deployed alongside it, so it appears it can't also find the MongoDB service, could it be why it says `crashloopbackoff`?

Here are the yaml files for the components I deployed:

MongoDB pod

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: mongodb
  labels:
    app: mongodb
spec:
  containers:
    - name: mongodb
      image: mongo
      ports:
        - containerPort: 27017
          name: mongodb-port
```

MongoDB service

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongodb # Same service name I used in my db url
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 27017
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: mongodb
  type: ClusterIP
```

Back-end pod’s service

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: journal-api-service
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 8080
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: http-port
  selector:
    app: journal-api
    tier: backend
  type: LoadBalancer
```

Back-end deployment

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: journal-api-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: journal-api
      tier: backend
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: journal-api
        tier: backend
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: shulaa/journal-api:v1
          name: journal-api
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
              name: http-port
```

and I created them in the exact order I provided it here.
The mongo and nodejs app containers run fine when I run them locally.

Comment: `Does not have minimum availability` means it cannot find a node to run your workload on - either the nodes do not have enough resources to run it or nodes are cordoned/unschedulable. Please also add the output of `kubectl get nodes` and `kubectl get all`. Could you also clarify what do you mean when you say "app isn't connecting to the database", given your app is failing to deploy. Is it failing to connect to the database, or to even deploy?

Comment: @jabbson the deployment works at first i think, because I was provided with the services external IP, as it's a loadbalancer, but then the application crashes, and I feel it's because it can't connect to the database, because I see `db error` in the logs". The application returns `db error` when it fails to connect to the database

Comment: Doing some research, I found this tutorial[1] in How to Connect to MongoDB from Node.js on App Engine flexible environment. I think this could be useful for your issue, or maybe can give you a better approach to find a solution.
[1]https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/nodejs-mongodb-on-appengine

Answer (score 1):

That's due to the

```
Does not have minimum availability
```

your container is not coming up or running due to a resource outage. No resources into the cluster to run the container.

Now you should add New node so K8s can allocate some resources to container, or delete running pods.

You check Node status using the

```
kubectl get nodes
```

check resource of Nodes

```
kubectl top nodes
```

if your nodes as resources left there could be a chance no resource left GCP side in zone or so

> Wait. Google Cloud does not have enough resource available in the
> Region/Zone that you are trying to launch into. In some cases, this
> took an hour to an entire day.
>
> Select a different Region/Zone.